# Raspberry Pi [Errno 121] Remote I/O Error with Temperature Sensor

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, hardware, gpio, i2c

I'm trying to setup a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with a [Waveshare BME280 Environmental Sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P4CWGGK). I followed [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2016/07/using-bme280-i2c-temperature-pressure-sensor-in-python/) to wire the cables and ran the supplied bme280.py script. My sensor has 2 additional cables, the CS and ADDR/MISO, that are not present in the model on the guide but the rest are plugged in to the same GPIO pins. The I2C and SPI interfaces are enabled and I am running the latest Raspbian OS Lite.

When I run the script, I get the following message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
 `File "bme280.py", line 172, in <module>`
  `main()`
 `File "bme280.py", line 161, in main`
  `(chip_id, chip_version) = readBME280ID()`
 `File "bme280.py", line 56, in readBME280ID`
  `(chip_id, chip_version) = bus.read_i2c_block_data(addr, REG_ID, 2)`
`OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error`

There's another odd issue: when I run `i2cdetect -y 1` I get every line with dashes, but if I run it a second time immediately after, I get x77 to show up, but x76 still doesn't.

I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66086911/how-to-solve-raspberry-pi-3b-bme280-remote-i-o-error) and tried modifying my /boot/config.txt file by adding `i2c_baudrate=100000` and rebooting but that did not fix it.

I made sure to test the pi using [gpiotest](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing) and the results came back as
`Skipped non-user gpios: 0 1 28 29 30 31`
`Tested user gpios: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27`
`Failed user gpios: None`

I had gotten similar issues using a DHT11 sensor and running Adafruit libraries and got an error signifying there was no data flowing from the sensor. I tried using several different sensors and Raspberry Pis and have reinstalled the OS several times over.
At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First of all you need to get properly what interface your sensor has (SPI or i2c) and what pins should be connected. If it is i2c as per your script, then you need to check pull up resistance on the SCL and SDA pins.

Comment: I used a multimeter to test the readings on the sensor wires. Touched the leads to ground and to data wires. When plugged into the 3.3V, both data wires (SCL & SDA) read ~3.3V. I also tested with a DHT11 sensor plugged into 5V and it the meter correctly read 5V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to create a very hacky solution to this issue.
Since i2cdetect seems to only read devices on the second (or later) times it is run, I decided to simulate running it inside the sensor script.

I added the following lines to my code:

```
import os
from time import sleep
os.system('i2cdetect -y 1')
sleep(0.1)
os.system('i2cdetect -y 1')
```

The output still shows the first i2cdetect command not reading any devices so I had to add a second one. I noticed sometimes both of them read no data so I added a 1/10th second sleep command.

This gets unnecessary output from the i2cdetect commands but I ignore it and only send the temperature data to my server.